# Three JS - Property 'addElement' does not exist on type 'LensFlare'

Tags: typescript, three.js

Hi I've been using threejs for a little bit and I'm currently trying to add a lens flare to my scene, just one.

I've been trying to follow the three js [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lens#webgl_lensflares)

I barely got into it when some errors appeared, it seems it cannot find `light.addElement()` or `new LensflareElement()`

I get the two following errors:

**Property 'addElement' does not exist on type 'LensFlare'**

**Cannot find name 'LensflareElement'**

I can't seem to find anything online about it, or whether it's been deprecated or modified, has anything happened to it? Sorry for what is probably a trivial-problem/easy-fix

I don't have enough rep to post images but here's a link to what it looks like:

[errors](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AW767_nwZdpxw98ucLabQ9jUqrZB_yp8ZdXEEHLfCiZZPIz0cLA_1iDAQKRQFiBEl8kO9bksSRgY128Z-34vIAR7JxRDcTHx-9EP23lrpfFtgYde8KCHtbjBwvyiPahLcYSECPXVsxBTLWGX8wYX3j0ZJcvJpR-Duv-dpY3sbIZpkWSV35bY7yQCfqgTfqCNMeLhJO-8OAj0HCuX51naMVl4rdWhtDl905zu0d3amQ4WBlnrNWsv_hLkkEOG0cmGNUwD3w_jYleVXkZUqZZedMoj530Um9aLfL133OhX270QYSlgBodVMjSQlUs23GGTymBfJBiPzivm_Ytvy3THcDW3edStx3LIUn2xx144W271SbtWajZxksArHwHCi_QKiW_3VPJlylHraoR7xJUlLt1yMducalhoK_o2YXiZwrOgW5miSZBdCnn6PHgtEmMwiAVEtcI8iyC7KRlgKRSfjy21Mnm9h8xbvNooQFom1nYJysMzAoG4GSCH9sFWt_xbJqRGxbBMX36tX-2r4Mc3CDKWvqhhudm98duT8trnjc7SNZjVpoQvK2GrmOG4whX6ItDzHSc2LyuQ77Qc8WQp7JquL-3WZi04_y0uFVS-_I-nMeMRajO6u_TfjZqlsw=w552-h157-no)

Answer (score 1):

You can clearly see it does not understand what a lensflare is, thats why addElement is highlighted. Try changing first line to `var lensflare = new THREE.Lensflare();` Also change LensflareElement to THREE.LensflareElement.

Comment: I'm using TypeScript, importing the three components as modules, I don't need the 'THREE' attached to the front, sorry I should've said that

Comment: @HazeyAce Well I'm not familiar with TypeScript but it looks like variable has not been initialized. Maybe change const to var?

Comment: It is initialised, TypeScript uses strict type definitions, as the identifier `lensflare` is never reassigned I am required to use `const` instead of `var`. Sorry for this man lol, any other ideas? :-)

Comment: Well, first thing I would do is copy paste the example and check if it works fine in my browser, then modify it to fit my project. Then rewrite vanilla Javascript to TS, this way you can check at what point it time it fails. It might be browser, example, lensflare implementation or TS problem, who knows.

Comment: Ahh man, that is the rational thing to do I suppose, ok I'll fiddle about and build in vanilla, see what I find, I'll come back to this at some point, cheers bro

Comment: Yeah, it is a really time consuming approach but most of the times it finds the problem.